# Webpack | how to override file resolution strategy?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, create-react-app

I need some help regarding adding a file resolver.

Use case:

For my project there are two repositories, one is a react application and the second one is a custom overriding repository.

Structure:

```
| -> custom
|           | -> src/App.jsx
| src
|    | -> App.jsx
|
```

I want to check if a file with the same path with respect to the root exists within the custom folder, that one should be picked.
I was able to achieve this with react-native application with the metro bundler, but I am unable to find anything similar on webpack.

Metro example:

```
const defaultResolver = require('metro-resolver').resolve;

module.exports = {
        resolver: {
                resolveRequest: (context, moduleName, platform, realModuleName) => {
                        if (!moduleName.includes('.png')) {
                                const projectRoot = context.projectRoot;
                                const defaultResolverResponse = defaultResolver(
                                        {
                                                ...context,
                                                resolveRequest: null,
                                        },
                                        moduleName,
                                        platform,
                                        realModuleName,
                                );
                                const filePath = defaultResolverResponse.filePath;
                                const toReturn = [
                                        filePath.slice(0, projectRoot.length),
                                        '/custom',
                                        filePath.slice(projectRoot.length),
                                ].join('');
                                if (context.doesFileExist(toReturn)) {
                                        return {...defaultResolverResponse, filePath: toReturn};
                                }
                        }
                        // Forward everything else to the default resolver
                        return defaultResolver(
                                {
                                        ...context,
                                        resolveRequest: null,
                                },
                                moduleName,
                                platform,
                                realModuleName,
                        );
                },
        }
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried to find similar solutions and was unsuccessful in doing so.

Please note that the solution I am trying to implement is with CRA using rewire.